# Multiplicar x veces un string segun otro dato

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo en un csv una tabla de datos de dos columnas, una indica un string y el segundo la cantidad de veces que se deberia repetir ese dato.

[image: tabla ejemplo]

No he logrado, generar un codigo que me lea la entrada (i,0) y me la multiplique (0,j) veces,

```
###cuenta =0 

def contador():

  global cuenta

  cuenta+=1

for i in df['Aforo']:

  contador ()

  for j in df['NOMBRESALON']:

    y=[j], cuenta

    print(y)
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Este código está indentado tal cual lo estás usando?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo del resultado esperado? Por ejemplo, ¿Para la fila de `B` deseas que el resultado sea `BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB`?